# hide a containerView doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

I have an issue with a `containerView` in `Objective-C.`

I have two `containerview` one above the other and I want to switch between them.
If I made a button in my `viewController` (so outside of a container view) and I execute this code, it works :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
    self.containerViewUnder.alpha = 1;
    self.containerViewTop.alpha = 0;
}];
```

But if I try to execute the same code with a button inside a container view, nothing happen...
did I do something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: When you say "one above the other" do you mean one _in front of_ the other?

Comment: one containerview is in top of the over. Both container are at the same position in the viewcontroller.

Comment: Give the top view hidden YES and  bottom view hidden NO. If you want to get back make it reverse.

Comment: I've got the same issue with the property hidden. If I give the top view hidden from a button outside of container it's work but from a button inside nothing happen...

Comment: I've got a beginning of solution... If I create the outlet from the external container view in storyboard (not from the container view inside the view controller) I can use hidden or alpha properties. But now the top container view is hidden but I can't interact with the under container view... It's like the top container continue to intercept all user touch.